# Are country tags considered "meta-tags"?

Tags: discussion

Just saw the post on the SO blog about removing meta-tags from the system.

For stack exchange sites, would country tags like `UK` or `US` or `Canada` be considered meta-tags?  They don't "stand on their own" as Jeff puts it, but yet they provide valuable information.  For example on the Home Improvement and Finance sites, locality plays an important role in understanding the question and the possible answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say no, especially on the Home Improvement and Finance sites - the laws that you have to abide by depend on your location. Plus, they do greatly help in filtering (especially in Finance - someone familiar with financial practices in the US only can ignore other countries). Care does have to be taken, however, to ensure that only questions that actually depend on location have a location tag.

But the big thing is that what is meta on one exchange might not be meta on another. On Stack Overflow, few (if any) questions, depend on location so these tags are just noise. On another exchange, they might be somewhat useful, but mostly meta. And on others they might actually make a difference. Every Exchange needs to address what is and is not meta on it. Some tags (like `beginner` and `subjective`) are always meta, though.

Comment: +1 for "Care does have to be taken, however, to ensure that only questions that actually depend on location have a location tag."

Answer (score 0):

In general, we should strongly avoid country-centric tags unless the need for them is **overwhelming**. This is, after all, why the "too localized" close reason exists.

I'd prefer to see some country specific discussion in individual answers as necessary rather than a bunch of duplicate questions tagged [us], [uk], [canada], [poland], [zimbabwe], [iceland], ad nauseam

Some related discussion here:
[Alternatives for <X> in <Country>](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349/alternatives-for-x-in-country)