# Edit link disable

Tags: discussion, edits

I am not editing any questions & answers because
edit link disable on `Stackoverflow`.

Comment: Everywhere? On all questions and answers? Have you suggested edits before and had a large number of them rejected? Is there already an edit pending on that question? We're going to need another hint...

Comment: Yes i have edited some questions and some are approved with +2 reputation and no pending but how to see rejected questions.

Comment: Here's the [list of all your suggested edits](http://stackoverflow.com/users/718224/advait-amin?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Clicking on `suggested edit` will show you if your edit was approved or declined, and by whom.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hmmm... [The edits you've suggested so far](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718224/advait-amin?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) have been fairly problematic.

Overall, 6 out of 12 have been rejected. That's exactly *half*, which is a very large percentage.

Looking at them more specifically:

- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/251007) you say "improved formatting", but it definitely didn't. It doesn't change the formatting at all. It adds and removes words from the question and the title, which ends up changing the meaning of the question. Moreover, it fails to remove obvious noise, like "Thanks".
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/251000) was approved, but one could definitely argue whether it should have been. Once again, you stop short of removing obvious noise from the bottom of the question, like "Thanks in advance Alan".
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/250893) actually looks to me like a pretty good edit, and it was approved. Only one problem: **you added the word "Thanks"**. Don't do that. We take noise like that *out*, not add it in. That's why the person who approved it had to click the "Improve" button and remove it themselves. That causes the reviewers extra work, and I would have rejected it for that reason.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/250843) was a bit contentious. Two users voted to reject it, and one to approve it. The majority won, and it was rejected. I probably would have approved it, because it *does* improve the question, even if it stops short of removing the "Thanks". But it really needs to remove the "Thanks" and capitalize proper nouns like "Facebook" and "Facebook Graph API".
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249450) was rightfully rejected—all you did was add a bunch of noise to the question. You also modified the person's code, which really isn't a good practice.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249449) appears to be your first attempt to make the previous edit. It's *absolutely terrible* in that it makes the answer **worse** than it was before. The code sample used to be formatted as code, and you removed that formatting. I can't understand why.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249426) has a similar problem as the previous one: you *remove* code formatting from a code block. I have no idea why. You *tried* to reformat the numbered list at the top, but didn't do that correctly. Be sure to read the editing help. I don't understand why the moderator approved it. Probably fatigue from processing so many of these suggested edits in a very short period of time.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249353) was also contentious—2 users voted to approve and 1 user voted to reject. I would have rejected it. All you did was remove "or something". That doesn't count as a substantive edit that improves the post in any meaningful way. Yeah, "or something" probably didn't need to be there. But it wasn't hurting anything, so this is just wasting the reviewers' time.
- More problematically, the previous edit was [your *second* attempt at editing this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249326). **It appears that you had the edit rejected the first time, so you tried again with exactly the same edit.** That's completely unacceptable, and if the second reviewers would have known, they'd have rejected it, too.
- [Once again, you add noise](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249319).
- [Once again, you add noise](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249296). I have no idea why this one was approved. Someone should contact those users who voted to approve it. You don't even make any bones about the fact that you're cluttering up the post with stuff we remove.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/249241) doesn't make much sense. You claim that your edit is to "give specific requirements", but **it doesn't give any requirements**. All it does is take information out of the question. That serves no purpose. The question is not better for your having touched it. You didn't remove the "Thanks in Advance" noise, or remove the superfluous bold that makes it hard to read.

If you're *not* banned from suggesting edits, you should be. Learn from the mistakes I've taken time to describe above and try again later.

Also, please read the answers to these questions carefully:

- [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
- [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/should-i-remove-this-from-a-post-or-title)

Comment: Can't believe I just typed all that out. Also, I put them in reverse chronological order. But I'm not going to fix it.

Comment: There's a rate limit on suggested edits, when too many are rejected.  It is temporary; the edit link will eventually return.