# I say Thank You and it gets edited out?

Tags: discussion, edits, down-votes, specific-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

I ended my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687557/newbie-confused-about-objectcontext-dbcontext-and-datacontext) with: "Thanks very much" and it was edited out and was down voted??

I also got down voted because I added irrelevant(according to the person who edited my post) tags?? I thought it was relevant.

Can someone please explain?

Comment: Please, provide a link to the question in question (no pun intended).

Comment: I've always been one to wonder why my "Thanks in advance" ending is edited out. Does it really have to be removed?

Comment: Some users consider it noise as it adds no *technical value* to the question. - see [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Would you expect "Thank you" in an encyclopedia? [*That's* what Stack Exchange will be](http://stackexchange.com/about), preferably. (cc. @ThePower)

Comment: Could not resist...

Comment: @Arjan, SO will never reach the quality required to become an encyclopedia, at least not with the current reputation system in place.

Comment: Too many question marks.

Comment: @Arjan I wouldn't read an encyclopedia when trying to resolve a programming issue.

Comment: (@Hristo, indeed, my "ultimately" does not translate the word I had in mind. Neither does "preferably" in which I changed it, but the time to edit my previous comment was running out... Also, feel free to read "documentation" for "encyclopedia", I hope you get the idea when reading the linked "about".)

Comment: @Arjan, SO is a Q&A site - not the same as a mere collection of information facts. Questions here are asked by human beings and answered by human beings, not AIs. I see nothing wrong with adding some human touch with an expression like "Thank you". Besides the [Etiquette](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) says: "Bring your sense of humor." Would you expect humour in an encyclopedia?

Comment: "Thank you", "Hi", "Kind regards", etc. are all noise. Any question or answer can exist perfectly fine without it. We all can simply assume the user is thankful, can't we? Let's keep the content as clean as possible.

Comment: @Hristo I'd say SO is somewhere between an encyclopedia and a Q&A site. There's some content that is "the" answer for the question. Either way, it's not a forum for one-on-one support. SO is aiming for content that is useful for future readers as well; that's why personal stuff gets edited out.

Comment: Very well, @Hristo, would you expect "Thank you" in a FAQ?

Comment: I assume questions are being polite by default unless it amounts to "hai, send teh codez plz" in which case no amount of thanks will ever fix the rudeness.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That had nothing to do with why [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687557/newbie-confused-about-objectcontext-dbcontext-and-datacontext) got downvoted. Generally, [we always removed thanks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-remove-from-posts-and-titles) from the body of posts. Your question was downvoted because **it does not show any research effort**, which is exactly what the downvote icon says when you hover over it.

Comment: Should be noted here too that the OP already had a score of `-4` **before** that edit was made - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11687557/timeline