# Topic is new or unfamiliar to me

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles)

Many questions state that the OP is new or unfamiliar with a particular topic.

Is this kind of information useful? Should it be edited out of the question?

[Update labels while checking network connection to hosts using thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14360846/299327) is an example of this.

Answer (score 9):

That kind of information is not useful, and detracts from the question.

It is a disguised apology, a way of saying "sorry for the dumb question". There really are no dumb questions, only low-quality or high-quality questions. We all started somewhere, and if I were to ask questions about home maintenance or french cuisine, they'd be pretty newbie-ish. That doesn't make such questions useless to *other* newcomers to the same subject.

I usually remove such statements.

Answer (score -2):

It is important to know the proficiency of the OP on a subject when you write an answer to a question. If you provide an answer that assumes the OP has some implicit knowledge that he/she doesn't, for being new to the subject, the doubts won't be solved

Comment: Considering the questions - and answers - are for everyone, and any future visitor, and not just the OP, should we then assume the lowest possible level of proficiency on all questions? I disagree. Questions should be answered with enough information to solve the issue at hand. Nothing more, or less.

Comment: I see, you have quite a point here, you convinced me. (I still consider important to know the level of proficiency of the OP, but in a broader sense of the question/answer being able to help other visitors within the same level of the OP; and the proficience level being infered because of the *question itself* and not some sort of written excuse)

Comment: I agree with that last point, as well. I was thinking about including something about being able to infer the proficiency level from the question, but decided not to. =)