# Got notification about suggested edit but no approve or reject buttons

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, notifications

What actions, if any, should I take in response to notifications about suggested edits?

I received a notification like this:

> An edit was suggested to your post " ... ", ***please review it***.

In my humble opinion, the edits were unnecessary, but not to the extent that I would want to roll them back or further edit my question.

What is unclear to me is whether I'm supposed to take some further action or not? Also, I'm unable to locate a pair of buttons such as:

```
  [ approve ]   [ reject ]
```

Here is the link to the post for which I received the above mentioned notification:

["Active (Debug)" versus "Debug"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427837/active-debug-versus-debug)

Comment: The edit was already approved. Look for a red 'Rejected' or green 'Approved' entry on the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1364529).

Comment: The mismatch might be in the fact that the suggested edit was approved before you had a chance to review it. In my opinion, messages like these are a bit pointless *but only because the suggested edits queue on Stack Overflow is constantly trawled and thus kept clean and empty*. It took all of four minutes - a long time! - for that edit to be approved.

Comment: Then after `Approved X ago:` it should state `no further action required`.  Otherwise it's confusing to the user.

Answer (score 3):

By the time you got to it the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1364529) was already approved.

In this case the edit was very much justified. It made your post cleaner and easier to read, and removed the extraneous information not needed to answer your question. See [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles)

Comment: It also might have been **rejected** meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of notifications related to editing of your posts:

1. If it was edited by a user with full edit privileges (diamond moderator or user with at least 2000 reputation points) you will get:

   > Your answer to [question title here] was edited

   or:

   > Your question [question title here] was edited.

   (Depending if your post was question or answer)
2. If it was edited by a user without full edit privileges (anonymous visitor or a user with less than 2K rep) then it means it need review and you get such notification:

   > An edit was suggested to your post [question title here], please review it.

   You will *not* get another notification if the edit is approved.

As  already said by others, since the suggested edit is placed in a public queue it's usually being reviewed (either approved or rejected) very quickly and only if you're fast enough you'll reach it in time.

Worth to mention in this context that your review decision as OP (author of the post) is *binding* meaning that even if two other users decided to reject but you decide to approve, it will get approved.