# Putting a 'label' in front of the title - Is this good or bad practice?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, title

I stumble upon questions like these:

- [jQuery: Give selector.method as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922434/jquery-give-selector-method-as-parameter-call-it)
- [PHP: Including a class in a method of another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320228/php-including-a-class-in-a-method-of-another-class)

**It seems to me that 'labeling' the question with [language:question] is redundant as the language is stated in the actual tags.**

What is the general opinion on this?

Comment: See [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009)

Comment: It's simply redundant... The tags (should) already contain this info...

Comment: It's redundant. However, it's not a good idea to edit them out either, if that's the only problem with the question.

Comment: I don't mind editing small flaws.

Comment: I have seen that. :-) Still, when editing it is better to focus on  posts with many problems than those with just a minor issue to fix.

Comment: Caught in the act. :p Yeah, I know what you mean. It's just that when I come accross these kind of posts, I see no real harm in enforcing the general style rules.

Comment: TAGS IN TITLES!  Slowly I turned... step by step... inch by inch...

Comment: Yeah, definitely OCDing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave them out. From the ["what not to put in your posts" post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles):

> **Non-Organic Tags**
>
> Tags in the title are perfectly acceptable as long as they get worked into the title appropriately and become a part of the actual question. Explicitly labeling the question with a tag at the beginning or end of the title by using the [tag] format or just separating the name of the tag from the question with a dash (or other character) is not acceptable. The question already has tagging features and it should be listed there instead.

Comment: This says enough: Explicitly labeling the question with a tag at the beginning or end of the title by using the [tag] format or just separating the name of the tag from the question with a dash (or other character) is not acceptable.