# Editing questions: To remove or not to remove

Tags: discussion, edits, etiquette, question-quality

I've recently started editing questions. While editing questions I almost always remove the **Thanks in advance** and **Thanks for your help** parts of the questions. I've read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) question which is very similar my question and I notice that the accepted answer and the comments that follow are more of a debate so as to remove the or no. Since most of the questions belong to newbies I am still confused and don't how to go about it. My point being:

a) If they are new they might like it if their questions remain friendly. I mean, won't you want a `human touch` to your questions (the debate and some answers point towards it)

b) As the accepted answer states, the reasons for removing them are:

1. It will leave even less room in the question preview so that we have more difficulty gauging what a question consists of by reading the preview.
2. It takes time to read and parse through those questions when I am trying to spend my time more efficiently reading through the actual question and figuring out how to appropriately answer it. If I have to start reading all the little side comments and snarky humor inserted in there it detracts from the overall message.
3. If this is supposed to be a website which is servicing more than just the primary author, we need to think about how we construct messages so that they appear more clearly to those searching on google for questions that match their own. If I am looking for a solution for question X, I want to find someone who had the same problem, not their short autobiography and formalities before getting to that actual question.

So, is there any guideline for editing questions? And if not, what do most people who edit questions follow?

Comment: We should also remove invalid use of backticks. You can start by editing your own posts and using bold or italics for highlight certain key words, NOT inline code formatting.

Comment: You already linked to the other question, and your post doesn't actually add anything to the discussion. That other post is such a  guideline; it reflects the community consensus. If you are editing anyway, address not just the taglines, address spelling, grammar and formatting as well.

Comment: As @ShadowWizard said, bold it is.

Comment: And @MartijnPieters I do address the other issues too. I was just wondering if we could add something to the FAQ and list out something more definitive regarding editing the questions.

Comment: Like this post you mean? [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009)

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian [kind of, yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137755/reject-an-already-approved-suggested-edit-when-rolling-it-back). In short, backticks means inline code. Things like "Thanks in advance" or "Stack Overflow" are not code, no matter how you look at it.