# Should posts be edited to be gender neutral?

Tags: discussion, edits

How much effort do we need to put into gender neutrality?

My post was just edited in this way in a question where I answered it myself.  Here's the screenshot of the edit:

[image]

The edit was titled "trim gender assumption". And, interestingly, the only people in the discussion to whom I was speaking were named "Noah" and "Dylan".

Maybe I'm overreacting. Maybe there's someone out there whose feelings will be spared as a result from this edit. I guess I'm just not thinking about these matters when I'm problem solving.

What are your thoughts? How vigorously should posts be vetted for gender-neutral language?

EDIT:
This post is receiving a lot of downvotes, which I understand.  When I originally posted this, I was definitely acting/speaking out of emotion.  Apologies.

In clear-headed retrospect though, I still find it very sad where society is going.  It seems difficult to address people with gender-specific pronouns in a forum without someone getting offended.  I was edited on a very old, unpopular post, where I was interacting with/speaking to 2 individuals.  None of them were offended by my alluding to their gender as male.

Comment: Eh... The edit summary was perhaps a bit too specific (editing out "thanks" of any kind is perfectly normal around here), but you're also overreacting here in some ways based on a *single* edit, so... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Call it a draw and get on with your night or whatever time of day it is where you are?

Comment: Just for your information, "Noah" is generally a female name where I live.

Comment: You could, if you really cared, go and ask at EL&U if `thanks for your time gents` is considered gender neutral, sexist, particularly disrespectful, and if it should be avoided. They might have a ball there, fever sometimes run high on these gender neutral language issues. I suppose the ubiquitous `guys` would have been suffice.

Comment: @wythagoras Really? Where do you live? Where I'm from (NYC, but US generally) "Noah" is almost exclusively a masculine name. Some of my female Israeli friends have names that sound like "Noah", but aren't spelled that way or etymologically related to it.

Comment: Why this question have -15? I each time understand less reasons why someone decide a question is useless. I think we doesn't have the right to ask? Even in meta? I saw someone requesting that a comment must forced to be written in order to put a negative point to give chance to improve the question. I totally agree with that. And also I inclined to think that parts of those negative points express disagree or the opinion that the question is too dummy.

Comment: @CarlosRafaelRamirez I voted on the initial revision, and given the  quality, tone and lack of research of that revision, it was 100% worth my down vote.

Answer (score 18):

That wasn't edit-worthy because of gender; it was edit-worthy because stuff like "hello" and "thank you" and "hope that helps" is considered to be superfluous on Stack Exchange.  See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011/162102) for more about that.

(I've now seen your update about the edit description.  Ok, maybe that editor did have a gender issue, but the whole phrase still qualifies as superfluous per the post I linked.)

Comment: Yeah, I understand that.  I suppose this whole rant should be titled: "My rant on today's political climate leaking into every orifice of media"

Comment: Superfluous nonsense  to say *thank you* in an edit, what has the world come to? I find that thinking more offensive than the term *gents*itself. But, yes, I have refrained myself from saying *thank you* in posts, I usually post my gratitude in the comments. which is worse?

Comment: Mari-Lou: here both are just noise, so will get edited out or flagged on many sites. You don't need to say thanks, just upvote helpful posts.

Comment: @Mari-LouA post content is meant to be durable, while the comments you replied to are not.  Three years later nobody needs to see that some "gents", now not identified because the comments have been flushed, helped you.  The best way to say thank you is to upvote useful content.  If you want to leave specific feedback for an answerer you can do that in a comment on the answer, if you have something more to say than just the thanks.  (For example, if an answer suggested multiple solutions, you might report which actually worked for you.)

Comment: So what was so useful about leaving "So it was a silly oversight on my part"? The OP answered their very own question and explained why and who helped him reach that conclusion. It was the OP himself who asked the question in the first place, and probably the person who benefitted the most. What's the big deal with saying a quick thank you in your own answer? You never said thank you in a post, ever?

Comment: -20 on a newcomer post, his first post on meta, and what was *so* bad about his question? Could it have been rephrased better? OK, yes. But the essence of the question was done in good faith.

Comment: Why are you asking me about the votes on the question?  I didn't downvote it, for the record.

Comment: General reflection on the OP's post, and how users have perceived his request. I didn't imply that you DV the post, it's none of my business anyway.

Answer (score 13):

A few things to consider:

- On-screen names are more often than not pseudonyms - there is no way of knowing the gender of any member, nor does it matter - hence the unnecessary need for an assumption.
- Crucially though, 'thank you' remarks are often considered as noise in a post and are often edited out.

Either way, it is a small correction that would not take away from the actual knowledge-sharing of your post - not worth the worry.

Comment: I understand that.  Then maybe we should be titling the edits as such, instead of infusing them with politics.

Comment: The edit description was provided by the editor, not SE.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you want your posts to be tirelessly vetted and criticized to
>   remove any hint of allusion to gender?

Well, I think the issue has more to do with "thanks" than "gents". Also, I don't see any reason why you have to use *any hint of allusion to gender* in any post. It is not necessary and note that there are many English names that are used by both males and females and it's always better not to use any gender-related terms.

Even if you had used "Thanks for your time, guys, folks, people, or ladies and gentlemen, etc.", this part would have been edited out.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers addressed the real issue here, I will try to do that.

Let's take a look at what you wrote:

> Thanks for your time gents!

OK. What is "gents"? Shortcut of "gentlemen". In essence, you thank only male readers. I can understand why female readers might get insulted by that, as their time is worth no less than others.

So just to keep it polite and non insulting, someone tried to **help you** by making it gender neutral. And that is it.

Comment: @ff524 since OP didn't provide any link, I can't possibly know that.

Comment: The OP does mention them by name `The only people in the discussion, to whom I was speaking were named "Noah", and "Dylan"`