# Should edits to one’s own answers be isolated and highlighted?

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, etiquette

I’ve observed that some answers include sections at the bottom that are explicitly labeled **Edit** or the like. But there are also many other answers that (as the system indicates) have been edited but bear no internal evidence of having been changed.

Are there rules or conventions about this? Do they vary by site? Do they depend on the nature or extent of the changes? Now that I think of it, would it depend whether one is editing one’s own answer or someone else’s? (I hope and trust that this cluster of questions coheres sufficiently to be tolerated in one place.)

I’ve searched here for “edit answers” but in vain.

Comment: TL;DR no, there's no policy for that, at least nothing set in iron. I'm sure it was discussed before, looking for such a dupe.

Comment: The canonical question is *[What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131009/what-should-i-keep-out-of-my-posts-and-titles/131011#131011)*, near *"Changelogs"* (part of the official FAQ).