# Including keywords to posts to facilitate searching

Tags: feature-request, search

I have a suggestion to make. I know it is beyond the scope of this site. But this will attract more people in various professional fields to use *[LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)* to make their drawings, and seek improving them or adding more features or elements.

My suggestion is to make some kind of indexing keywords to be included in posts related to various fields, for example medicine, dentistry, economics, music, architecture, ...etc.

It will facilitate finding elements in such fields, if there is a way to make indexing of drawings related to them.

For the existing posts, I suggest contacting the members, explaining my idea, if accepted, to encourage them including such keywords.

By time, drawings related to different fields will accumulate. It will be easier for professionals looking for certain elements needed in various fields, by searching such keywords to find what they are looking for to make their drawings.

Comment: So you're basically asking for [tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)?

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Yes, but tags related to professional fields, as medicine, architecture, ...etc., not related to latex features.

Comment: which ought to be covered by the specific subject centric sites?

Comment: You seem to want a collection of Latex templates for various purposes rather than a collection of Q&A about Latex. Stack Exchange (Specifically [tex.se]) is about the latter rather than the former. You can try to treat it as the former but you probably won't get great results. Why don't you try using sites that do provide the former like Overleaf?

Comment: Perhaps this request should be asked in [TeX - LaTeX META site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/) . And even there the feature request would possibly be rejected.

Comment: Can you add some examples? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: Questions on stackexchange sites should try to be as abstract as possible so that as many people as possible will find them useful. For your recent problem about positioning tikz pictures, it does not matter if they show a head, an x-ray tube or something else. You could have demonstrated the same problem with a couple of circles. A more abstract question about how to position predefined images would make it much easier for users with a similar problem to find a solution.

Comment: If you want to show off your image, something like https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ would be much better suited than adding unnecessary information to stackexchange posts.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
Thank you very much for your suggestion. Can I create a tag, for example: Dentistry? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: @Hany https://texample.net/tikz/examples/contribute/

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
Thank you very much for your prompt reply. I think this would be the solution to my suggestion.